# Does a small perturbation push the minimizing point of continuous function too far?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, compactness, maxima-minima, perturbation-theory

Let $(M,\,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f,\,g: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ two continuous functions.

For $|ε|<1$ we define a perturbation of $g$: $$g_ε(x) = g(x) - εf(x)$$

For every $ε>0$, there exist some $x_ε\in M$ such that $\displaystyle g_ε(x_ε) = \min_{x\in M}g_ε(x)$, since $g_ε$ is continuous and $M$ is compact.

The same argument applies for $g$, too, but suppose that the according minimizer $x_0$ is unique.

Can we argue that for small $ε$ we can find a $x_ε$ $δ$-close to $x_0$ for $δ\xrightarrow{ε\rightarrow 0} 0$?

How can we get around it?

Every help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to show that any accumulation point taken from $\operatorname{argmin}  g_{1 \over n}$ will be an element of $\operatorname{argmin}  g$:
Suppose $g_{1 \over n}( x_{1 \over n}) \le g_{1 \over n}(x)$ for all $n,$ and $x \in M$. Suppose $x^*$ is an accumulation point of $x_{1 \over n}$, then taking limits along an appropriate subsequence gives: $g(x^*) \le g(x)$ for all $x$.

Hence if $\operatorname{argmin}  g$ is a singleton, any sequence taken from $\operatorname{argmin}  g_{1 \over n}$ must converge to this point. To see this note that any subsequence of $x_{1 \over n}$ must contain a further subsequence that converges to $\operatorname{argmin}  g$. Hence $x_{1 \over n}$ converges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @SotirisSimos: Let me know it the above edits are sufficient.

Comment: sorry, I fell asleep, I'm not really sure I understand the second argument. You're saying that there is a subsequence of $x_{1/n}$ that converges to some $x^* \in M$ and for that point we have $g(x^*) \leq g(x)$ due to uniform convergence of $g_{1/n}$ to $g$, so that $x^* \in \operatorname{argmin} g$. But I can't follow the rest of the argument!

Comment: There is an analysis result that says that $x_n \to x^*$ **iff** every subsequence contains a further subsequence that converges to $x^*$. It is a surprisingly useful result.

Comment: Thank you once again! You were very insightful! Let me ask you something, though! You did prove something more, right? I mean, in my case, we have that every sequence has a subsequence which converges to some point which turns out to be the unique minimizing point of $g$. So, we can choose a point from the subsequence as close to it as we want. Am I right? It's not that I don't appreciate that you proved something more, on the contrary! I'm just clarifying things!

Comment: If $g$ has a unique minimiser $x^*$ then any sequence of $g_\epsilon$ minimisers will converge to $x^*$. If $g$ does not have a unique minimiser, then you can find a subsequence of the $g_\epsilon$ minimisers that converges to one of the $g$ minimisers.

Comment: Another useful result, for sure! Unfortunately, it does not answer my question! What I want to learn is if it's enough to show that for some converging subsequence of minimizers, its limit equals the unique minimizer of $g$, which is your first argument, since then we can take some point from the subsequence (which is a point from our original sequence) to be close to the minimizer of $g$.